# New Years Resolution: Move from Classic ASP to ASP.NET MVC. Where do I start?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I can write Classic ASP with my eyes closed, and can do it well. Frankly, I've only not moved to newer technologies because I haven't had a project that couldn't be done in Classic ASP (VBScript). However, my New Years resolution is to finally make the jump. I must state in advance that because I like VB, I hate C#, but I'm willing to learn. I've done a little C# in the desktop world, but never in the web world.

I've been reading all week, but my biggest hurdle is that it doesn't seem like these newer technologies let me code in the same manner I had been: inline in the pages. Now, I realize that most people think this is beneficial, but this is a huge leap for me.

**Without my laying out my preconceived notions and things I think I've learned in the past week, where do you all think is the best place to start?** I'm in my 30s now, so I probably don't pick things up like I used to. With that said, the learning curve is probably steeper for me now than it would have been in 2003 when I should have done this. Other than some valid links, what are some of the impediments I'll come across as I start this journey?

Comment: Classic ASP to MVC is not a huge jump *(compare to  Web Form to MVC)*. Since you have a lot of experience in .Net, I'll say [Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Experts-Voice-ASP-Net/dp/1430265299/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420672264&sr=8-1&keywords=asp.net+mvc+5) could be a good start. VB and C# are just syntax different *(language differences are very minor)*; you can switch to C# very easily.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the reasoned approach. That lessens my fears greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your position I would probably do the following. It sounds like you have access to Visual Studio. Since you have some experience with VB, I would pick a simple project that you did in VB and see if you can recreate it starting from a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application Template. The main concept in MVC 4 (at least new to me) was how to use 'Razor' to display server data. It can be used to write inline code in C# but there are a few conventions that can save you a lot of HTML coding. There is also the partial view concept which can save you a lot of work. There are quite a few useful You-Tube videos out there. In particular, I think this guy https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAo_CcePreaRTa3gQZBjWfA did a nice job teaching how to make Ajax requests in an MVC 4 application.

Good Luck!